# If $f(g(x))=\sin(x)$ and $f'(x)=1-[f(x)]^2$, then prove $g'(x)=\sec(x)$

Tags: calculus

> Considered $f$ is a function derivative, $f(g(x)) = \sin(x)$ and derivative of $f'(x)=1-[f(x)]^2$. Proof that derivative of $g'(x) = \sec(x)$.

I need help me because, my answer un the proof is only $\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the chain rule, and then substituting with information given in the question:

$$f'(g(x)) g'(x) = \cos(x)$$

$$(1-[f(g(x))]^2) \ g'(x)= \cos(x)$$

$$(1-\sin^2x)g'(x) = \cos(x)$$

$$g'(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=\sec x$$